# Why the user account status is not changed

Tags: oracle

A user account 'john' use a default profile,`FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS` is set to 10.Password has been entered incorrectly 11 consecutive times and prompt

> 'ORA-28000,the account is locked'.

On Database Control,the user account status is `'LOCKED(TIMED)'`.But when i execute following select sentence：

```
select username,account_status 
from dba_users 
where username = 'john';
```

the result is :

```
USERNAME|   ACCOUNT_STATUS
--------|-----------------
john    |       OPEN
```

why the status is still open?

Comment: Are you using a standby database?

Comment: no standby database

Comment: As the status in LOCKED(TIMED) there is a chance it may have unlocked after PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME limit. I believe it would have set to 1 by default still just to cross check.

Comment: Cloud Control uses the same system views as you, so there could not be any difference. You either looking in another database, looking at another user or someone/something is unlocking the user while you're running your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that i made a mistake.

In order to test that letters composed of username are case sensitive,i had created a username `'john'`,and another username was specified with double quotes which is `"john"`.

The letters are case sensitive but will be automatically converted to uppercase,with the exception of letters within quotes.On Database Control,the user account `JOHN`'s status is `'LOCKED(TIMED)'`,but when query through sqlplus,i ignore the quotes that lead to return account_status of the `'john'` practically.

It should execute following select sentence：

```
select username,account_status 
from dba_users
where username = 'JOHN';
```

and it would return user account status correctly:

```
USERNAME| ACCOUNT_STATUS
--------|----------------
JOHN    |  LOCKED(TIMED)
```